# Installing Ubuntu 13 on Clean Mac?

Tags: installation, mac

I have a cleanly wiped MacBook Pro. When I say cleanly wiped I mean the only way the computer will turn on is if I run it in recovery mode. I was given it for free the other day from my friend as he was upgrading, but it currently has no installation of OSX on it. Is their a way to install Ubuntu through the terminal or another manner? Any suggestions would be awesome.

Sparkeyy

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you will have another PC.

Either do a Live USB, or a Live CD. I recommend the Live CD.

Instructions are here:

### Windows

[Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)

[Live USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

### OSX

[Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx)

[Live USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

### Ubuntu

[Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)

[Live USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

Insert your Live USB/CD into the Mac. It will come up with this screen:

[image]

The arrow is something else. Just ignore it.

Choose 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.

It will come to the Ubuntu desktop. When you're ready, click the 'Install Ubuntu' on the desktop.

Set it up, and you are done!

Hope this helps!!!